# Packaging multiple items in an Android APK

Tags: android, apk

If I create an application for Android, how do you package extra items in with it like a live wallpaper or widgets?  For example, google maps does this by including a live wallpaper with the download of the latest version.
On a related note, with google maps, it's available for, I believe, 1.6 and up, but it seems that it is all the same download.  So how do you ensure that, even though there may be a 2.x only feature included, it still shows up for lower OS phones?  Or is the marketplace maybe actually holding onto two separate APKs for each OS?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2567030/showing-live-wallpaper-in-a-1-6-target-app-by-detecting-if-its-a-2-1-device

Comment: What about if you wanted to install a Provider that other apks will use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know anything about live wallpapers, but widgets aren't really a separate item from the app; if you read [the development guide about widgets](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html), you'll see that they're actually just another component of an application.

I'm not sure what you're getting at for the second question.  Are you asking how Google Maps is deployed for multiple platforms?  If so, maybe you should check the answer I posted to [your last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2621996/android-app-using-2-x-apis-that-will-also-run-on-1-x) (which is more focused on multiple platform deployment).  The specifics I don't know; I'm not sure if they're two separate APKs or if Google just used their backwards compatibility.

Comment: Yes live wallpapers are simply a type of Service that you publish in your manifest (with the appropriate action and meta-data).